# Render-blocking CSS in PageSpeed - single file

Tags: html, css, npm, gulp, pagespeed

I'm testing optimization best practises for front-end. So I have learned using gulp and npm to merge and minify my CSS and JS files to single all.min.css and js.min.css

In Google PageSpeed I have warning "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". So I added "async" to my js script.

```
<script async src="/dist/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Works ok, but what to do with my .css file?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/all.min.css">
```

This is SINGLE css file in my website (33kb). It includes bootstrap, font-awesome, few small libaries and my style.css.

It is good practise to include that big file in html source? I'm doing something wrong? I want to get at least once that 100 points, but not by making something stupid, not practical.

Answer (score 3):

The Google PageSpeed tool offers general guidelines, not actual speed measurements. Thus, you should not lose any sleep if you're not getting a perfect 100 points.

That said, the optimal way to deliver your CSS without "blocking above-the-fold rendering":

- Add all styles that are necessary for above-the-fold content as inline styles in the HTML head. For example:

  ```
  <style>
      #logo {
          // ...
      }
      #navigation {
          // ...
      }
      .hero-banner {
          //
      }
  </style>
  ```
- Load the remaining styles (concatenated and minified into one file in your case) asynchronously, which is typically done via deferred or asynchronous javascript before the closing body tag. Example:

  ```
  <script>
      var deferstyles = document.createElement("link");
      deferstyles.rel = "stylesheet";
      deferstyles.href = "/dist/css/all.min.css";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(deferstyles);
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move the CSS file to the bottom of your page so that the HTML loads before the CSS.

Be are that this can cause a flash of unstyled content,

> A flash of unstyled content (FOUC, also flash of unstyled text or FOUT)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)[2] is an instance where a web page appears briefly with the browser's default styles prior to loading an external CSS stylesheet, due to the web browser engine rendering the page before all information is retrieved.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Comment: You could prevent this by simply adding inline-style `display: none;` on body and then in later-loaded css file `.body { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

You got the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/all.min.css">
```

in your pages `<header>` . that's common practise. 
Pagespeed Insights wants you to remove it there and place it after your content ("below-the-fold" => after the content that is visible on screen on page load without scrolling). 
for example place it in your footer.